# Should I use sync or blocking channels?

Tags: go

I have several go routines and I use **unbuffered channels** as sync mechanism.

I'm wondering if there is anything wrong in this(e.g. compared with a WaitGroup implementation). A known **"drawback"** that I'm aware of is that two go routines may stay blocked until the 3rd(last) one completes because the channel is not buffered but I don't know the internals/what this really means.

```
func main() {
    chan1, chan2, chan3 := make(chan bool), make(chan bool), make(chan bool)
    go fn(chan1)
    go fn(chan2)
    go fn(chan3)
    res1, res2, res3 := <-chan1, <-chan2, <-chan3
}
```

Comment: The answer to this question depends on your actual problem and your actual constraints.

Comment: I just wondered if there could be a congestion/race issue. For example the program getting stuck  / deadlock for some reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation isn't inherently worse or better and I've written code of this style in favor of using a `WaitGroup` with success. I've also implemented the same functionality with `WaitGroup` and had roughly the same results. As mentioned in the comments which is better is situational, and likely subjective in many cases (the difference will be in maintainability or readability rather than performance).

Personally, I really like this style for a situation where I'm spinning off one worker per item in a collection. I was already encountering a lot of pains with shutting down cleanly (signaling on an abort or close channel which had to be made available to the worker methods one way or another) so I thought it was very convenient to take that communication loop one step further and enclose all the work in a channel select. In order to have a working abort you kind of have to anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Channels and `WaitGroup`s are both available for you to use as appropriate. For a given problem, your solution could be solved using channels or `WaitGroup` or even a combination of both.

From what I understand, channels are more appropriate when your goroutines need to communicate with each other (as in they are not independent). `WaitGroup` is usually used when your goroutines are independent of each other.

Personally, I like `WaitGroup` because it is more readable and simpler to use. However, just like channels, I do not like that we need to pass the reference to the goroutine because that would mean that the concurrency logic would be mixed with your business logic.

So I came up with this generic function to solve this problem for me:

```
// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

```
func1 := func() {
        for char := 'a'; char < 'a' + 3; char++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        }
}

func2 := func() {
        for number := 1; number < 4; number++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        }
}

Parallelize(func1, func2)  // a 1 b 2 c 3
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util